# Show this set forms a vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces

This is a rather simple question but I am trying to understand where I make my errors. Let $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ be the vector space of all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, with addition and scalar multiplication defined pointwise. Does this set of functions form a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$?

a) the set $\{f\in C:|f(t)|\leq1\text{ for all }t\in[0,1]\}.$

**Attempt:**

To determine if it is a subspace, we need to check the conditions of being non-empty (I assume it is the same as checking whether it contains the zero vector, correct me if I am wrong), closed under addition, and closed under scalar multiplication.

1. The zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ is the function $0(t) = 0$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$. In this case, the function $0(t)$ satisfies $|0(t)|\leq 1$ for all $t\in[0,1]$. Therefore, the set contains the zero vector.
2. Let $f$ and $g$ be two functions in the set, i.e., $|f(t)|\leq 1$ and $|g(t)|\leq 1$ for all $t\in[0,1]$. We need to show that $f+g$ is also in the set. For any $t\in[0,1]$: $|(f+g)(t)|=|f(t)+g(t)|\leq|f(t)|+|g(t)|\leq1+1=2.$ But I am not sure how does $|f(t)|+|g(t)|\leq2$ show it is closed under addition.
3. Let $f$ be a function in the set, i.e., $|f(t)|\leq 1$ for all $t\in[0,1]$, and let $c$ be a scalar. For any $t$ in $[0,1]$, $|(cf)(t)|=|c\cdot f(t)|=|c|\cdot|f(t)|\leq|c|\cdot1=|c|.$ I am not sure how does $|c\cdot f(t)|\leq|c|$ show it is closed under multiplication?

Comment: Is $|c|$ always going to be less than or equal to $1$?  Is $2$ a scalar?  Is $2$ less than or equal to $1$?  No?  Then what does that imply?

Comment: @JMoravitz 1) I tried combining this inequality $|f(t)|\leq1$ with $|c|\cdot|f(t)|$, so I got $|c|\cdot|f(t)|\leq|c|\cdot1=|c|.$ Now intuitively I don't think that $|c|$ is always going to be less than or equal to $1$, but I can't see where I made the error 2) I got $|f(t)|+|g(t)|\leq1+1=2$ by having in mind that $|f(t)|\leq1$ and $|g(t)|\leq1$, so their sum is less or equal than to 2?

Comment: Your error is in incorrectly assuming that you are supposed to be able to show that the set actually does make a vector space.  It doesn't.  The set is not a subspace and you see this by constructing a simple example of where it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $U:=\{f\in C:|f(t)|\leq1\text{ for all }t\in[0,1]\}.$ This set can not be a subspace of $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ because it is not closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Let $f,g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be defined by
$$f(t)=g(t)=\frac{2}{3}.$$
Note that $f,g\in U$, because $\vert f(t)\vert=\frac{2}{3}\leq1$ and $\vert g(t)\vert=\frac{2}{3}\leq1$  for all $t\in[0,1]$. However, $f+g\notin U$, because
$$\vert (f+g)(t)\vert=\vert f(t)+g(t)\vert=\frac{4}{3}>1.$$

Now, let $c=3$ and $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be defined by $f(t)=\frac{2}{3}$. Thus, $c\in\Bbb R$ and $f\in U$. However, $cf\notin U$, because
$$\vert (cf)(t)\vert=\vert cf(t)\vert=2>1.$$

Answer (score 2):

This set of functions can be shown not to form a subspace by making a counterexample. $f(x)=x$ is in the set as $|f(x)|=|x|\le 1$, but $2f(x)$ is not contained in the set as $2f(1)=2\gt1$. Therefore the set is not a vector space.

Comment: I think you need to look more carefully at the domain for the functions --- it's the whole real line, not just the unit interval. Perhaps replace your $f$ with $f(x) = 0.8$.

Comment: @JohnHughes the example still works, it is just missing a phrase obvious from context... "*...is in the set as $|f(x)|=|x|\leq 1$ for all $x\in [0,1]$, but $2f(x)$ is not as $2f(1)=2>1$*"

Comment: It's obvious to *us*; it's not clear that it'd be obvious to the OP, who's evidently learning this for the first time.